# Infinite loading with script tag inside iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

Here is code, stuck with that simple issue which I never have had in past 7 years:

```
<html>
<body>
    <iframe></iframe>
    <script>
        window.frames[0].document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"><\/scr' + 'ipt>');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that browser's spin wheel continue to circle.

Network console shows all loaded.

If I remove iframe from DOM, or add/change @src attribute - loading stops.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the first answer is the better way, but I'll provide a second answer that is almost identical to your code, but shows how calling `document.close()` would have also solved your issue.

The issue is that you've started writing to the document's `<head>` element in the iFrame, but not finished (that's why the page keeps loading). Calling `document.close()` signals that you've finished writing to the document.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <iframe></iframe>
    <script>
      var doc = window.frames[0].document
      doc.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"><\/scr' + 'ipt>');
      doc.close();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Saved me countless hours

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I've just found solution that works if you have control on inner script (doesn't help with loading 3rd party like jQ though).

You should close "current stream" with `document.close()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try just:

```
window.frames[0].document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"><\/script>');
```

I checked on JSbin and it works ok. 
[Example page](http://jsbin.com/gijuvezugi/edit?html,css,output)

---

#### Update:

I think it cannot work because that `iframe` doesn't even have any document in it. it's just an empty tag until it has a working `src` and is populated.
See [demo](http://jsbin.com/gijuvezugi/edit?html,css,output)

Anyway, this can only work if the content of the iframe is on the same domain (google "cross-origin iframes"). There is a "race" going on here. you want to load jQuery so the page your are loading would use it, but you cannot load any script from the outside of the iframe to the inside until the page has loaded inside the iframe...

Comment: yes I know, as I said in the update, what you are trying to do shouldn't be done (before it was loaded)..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like firefox might have some weirdness around iframes

```
<html>
  <body>
    <iframe></iframe>
    <script>setTimeout(function(){window.frames[0].document.write("hi");}, 5000);</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This results in a spinner that starts 5 seconds after page load and doesn't go away (at least on my computer - firefox 47.0)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to insert the script without the loading issue you describe by defining and appending the element in Javascript, without any loading issues.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <iframe id="myFrame"></iframe>
    <script>
      var jq = document.createElement('script')
      jq.type = 'text/javascript'
      jq.src = '//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js'
      document.getElementById('myFrame').contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(jq);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Of course, changing `body` to `head` will change where the script loads in the iFrame.

Comment: In my current situation, I don't have control on iframe inserting code that does `document.write`.

Comment: But I got the point - if there is no opening stream with `document.write` you don't need to close it with `document.close`.

Comment: While I think that this is the better way, I've added another answer that should help in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

May use the onload

```js
function populateIFrame() {
        const str = `<body></body>`;
        const idoc = document.getElementById("demo01")
        idoc.contentDocument.write(str)
        idoc.close();
}

window.onload=populateIFrame
```